# How to compare Factor and Principal Component Analysis results?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am currently working on an assignment where I am to perform a comparison of different Dimension Reduction techniques in Python. I am using the Scikit-learn functions to perform PCA and FA. However I am not sure what is the best way to compare the two in terms of "success". I was thinking I could compare how many "new features" (principal components vs factors) is needed to explain a certain % of the variance in the observations. However, I do not know how to calculate this for the Factor Analysis results? The PCA has the explained_variance-attribute, but I don't see an equivalent for FA.

Also, if someone has a better suggestion for comparing the two techniques in terms of success - Pit would be great :)